# Open CSV in Excel over Interop only reads first line

Tags: c#, .net, excel, csv

I have a CSV file and I want open it in an Excel and save it as an xlsx again. The reason I wanna do it this way, rather than write the data to an Excel file directly is that I hope it's faster that way since writing the data is very slow.

My csv looks like this:

```
sep=,
header1, header2, header3
data1, data2, data3
```

And here is my code to write the data to a CSV, open it in Excel and save it again:

```
var csvPath = [MyCSVPath];
File.WriteAllBytes(csvPath, WriteCsv(result));

excel.Workbooks.Open(csvPath, Delimiter: ",");

// Save the excel localy and load it's bytes again.
var path = [MyExcelPath]

workbook.SaveCopyAs(path);
excel.Workbooks.Close();
```

When I open the csv in the excel manually it is opened correctly. But when I do it over the code above it contains only the first line. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, your code sample is not complete. But the following code works fine in Excel 2016 for your csv file example. By default `SaveCopyAs` doesn't change initial format, but `SaveCopy` allows to define format explicitly.

```
var excelApp = new Application();
excelApp.Workbooks.Open("d:\\1.csv", Delimiter: ",");

var workbook = excelApp.ActiveWorkbook;
// this saves in same CSV format
workbook.SaveCopyAs("d:\\2.xlsx");
// this saves to correct xlsx format
workbook.SaveAs("d:\\3.xlsx", XlFileFormat.xlOpenXMLWorkbook);

workbook.Close();
excelApp.Quit();
```

Comment: you've right. thought I just left away not needed code. But as it turns out, it was an option I set for the workbook. Thanks!